# Bootstrap Navbar Dropdown Menu Issue in IPAD

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ipad, drop-down-menu

I had a small doubt in Bootstrap Navbar - Dropdown. The Dropdown doesn't seem to work in Ipad, I mean after opening the dropdown, If we tap/click on other area its not closing.

Could anyone please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of googling; I made up my own code. Bootstrap reference links to work on ipad: http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/browsers-devices/#modals-navbars-and-virtual-keyboards

```
//This Code is to detect if its an IPAd 
var isiPad = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null;

if(isiPad){
    $('body').css('cursor','pointer');

    $(document).on('touchmove',function(e){

      if($('.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.dropdown').hasClass('open'))
      {
        $('.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.dropdown').removeClass('open');
      }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    /*ipad popover or dropdown touch issue*/
 $(document).on('touchstart',function(e){
//e.preventDefault();
if($('.my_popover').length>0)
{
    /*enable element click*/
    if($(e.target).parents('.popover').length==0){
   /*main ipad popover*/
    $("#my_account").popover("hide");           
}
}       
});
```